# Keep the original value from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, django, csv, pandas

I have a csv file and it is in the following format:

```
A, -0.1234540756893158
B, 0.123450496711731
C, 0.12345994493484497
D, -0.12345484461784363
E, 12344656.0
F, -1234648.0
G, 12342316.0
H, 12552.37109375
I, 16247.228515625
J, -12.123796875
K, 1081104201
L, 123
```

I am reading it with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/output.csv', header=None, names=['c1','c2'])
```

Then I will get the interesting indexes as follows, and save it in a csv:

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
df[df.index.isin(my_list)].to_csv(thefile2, sep=',', header=None, index = False)
```

But when I check the content of "thefile2", I get such an output:

```
A,-0.123454075689
B,0.123450496712
C,0.123459944935
D,-0.123454844618
E,12344656.0
F,-1234648.0
G,12342316.0
H,12552.3710938
I,16247.2285156
J,-12.123797
K,1081104201.0
L,123.0
```

As it can be seen, values for A, B, C, D, H, I and J are rounded up, and K and L are having a 0 at the end. in the output file. My question is, how can I get the original values in the second column?

Comment: Is possible read `c2` as `string` ? `pd.read_csv('/output.csv', header=None, names=['c1','c2'], dtype=str)` ?

Comment: thanks, thats the answer! maybe you can write it in the answer section, if you need the bounty :D

Comment: pandas has inferred the dtype to be float here as you have fractional values, this is expected behaviour, note that simply preserving the text representation here for writing out maybe useful here but you'd need to set the dtype everytime you want to process this csv so what is the real problem here as this is the appropriate dtype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter `dtype=str` for cast all values to `string` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
pd.read_csv('/output.csv', header=None, names=['c1','c2'], dtype=str)
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""A,-0.1234540756893158
B,0.123450496711731
C,0.12345994493484497
D,-0.12345484461784363
E,12344656.0
F,-1234648.0
G,12342316.0
H,12552.37109375
I,16247.228515625
J,-12.123796875
K,1081104201
L,123"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), header=None, names=['c1','c2'], dtype=str)
print (df)
   c1                    c2
0   A   -0.1234540756893158
1   B     0.123450496711731
2   C   0.12345994493484497
3   D  -0.12345484461784363
4   E            12344656.0
5   F            -1234648.0
6   G            12342316.0
7   H        12552.37109375
8   I       16247.228515625
9   J         -12.123796875
10  K            1081104201
11  L                   123

print (type(df.loc[0, 'c2']))
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: The question author, and other visitors to this page, might find it convenient if I mention that values in the second column can be read to their full precision in floating point using this statement: `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), header=None, names=['c1','c2'], dtype={'c1': str,'c2':np.float64})`